# Hyperledger Fabric orderer Variable configuration

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, ibm-blockchain

Can anyone tell me at the time of configuration of orderer what does`ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS` this variable should contain ?

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

This should contain the file path of the X.509 certificates of the Root CA for TLS communication. An example is provided here. 
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.2/first-network/base/docker-compose-base.yaml#L24

Comment: then why it is array .There will be only 1 root CA .

Answer (score 0):

This should contain the TLS certificate of orderer and all peer as like below

ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/etc/hyperledger/crypto/orderer/tls/ca.crt, /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peerOrg1/tls/ca.crt, /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peerOrg2/tls/ca.crt, /etc/hyperledger/crypto/peerOrg3/tls/ca.crt]

Comment: Why it is an array? Why it contains TLS certificates of peers?